# jQuery functions, setInterval or created function, not working

Tags: jquery, css, html

Im trying to create a slideshow on a webpage. I pasted the whole code just in case I missed something. I tried including the jquery library by link and file. I also tried including the js code in html and as a seperate file, but still no results. Its only showing the buttons and no images, I removed the display:none part in style and images are there.

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
    </script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/
                                 1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/
                 1.10.4/jquery-ui.min.js">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js\jquery.js">
    </script>
    <style type="text/css">

    .slider{
        width: 600px;
        height: 350px;
        margin: 30px auto;
        background-image: url(ajax-loader.gif);
        background-position: center;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
    }

    .slider img{
        width: 600px;
        height:350px;
        display: none;
    }

    .shadow{
        background-image: url(C:\Users\socsci1\Desktop\slider\
                              images\shadow.png);
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: top;
        width: 664px;
        height: 144px;
        margin: -60px;
    }

    a{
        padding: 5px 10px;
        background-color: #F0F0F0;
        margin-top: 30px;
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #555;
    }
    a.right {
        float: right;
    }
    a.left {
        float: left;
    }

    </style>


    <script type="text/javascript">

    function Slider (){
        $(".slider#1").show("fade",500);
        $(".slider#1").delay(5500).hide("slide",{direction:'left'},500);

    var sc = $(".slider img").size();
    var count = 2;

        setInterval(function(){
        $(".slider#"+count).show("slide",{direction: 'right'},500);
        $(".slider#1").delay(5500).hide("slide",{direction:'lefty'},500);

        if (count == sc) {
            count = 1;
        }else {
            count = count+1;
            }
        },5000);
    }
    </script>
    </head>

    <body onload="Slider();">

    <div class ="slider">
            <img id="1" src="images/number-1.jpg" border="0" />
            <img id="2" src="images/number-2.jpg" border="0" />
            <img id="3" src="images/number-3.png" border="0" />
            <img id="4" src="images/number-4.jpg" border="0" />
        <a href="#" class="left">Previous</a>
        <a href="#" class="right">Next</a>
    </div>

    <div class="shadow"></div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: IDs should not consist purely of numbers. HTML5 allows it, but it's still not a good idea.

Comment: Also, ids are unique so you do not have to specify the class. Therefore $('.slider#1') can just be made $('#1').

Comment: what seems to be the problem? what is not working? are you getting any js errors? provide link to live version (fiddle or codepen will work as well)

Comment: @LorDex I edited the post to include it. As im not running in a compiler just checking the html file using a web browser.

Comment: size() is deprecated, use length instead. you got multiple jquery vesions included.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears you're lacking a space in your selector which means you're targeting at the wrong level.

To target the child of a parent by the parent's class you use:
`$('.parentclass childSelector')` - note the space - where `childSelector` in your case is `#1`.
This gives you `$('.slider #1')`.

In your case, and as *msquitieri* mentions, you're using an `Id` which must be unique in your HTML. Therefore you can find it directly $("#1") for example.
The benefit of using the parent selector is that it narrows down the context of the search that you're doing, which may be of use if you have a large DOM that would be traversed.

For your problem (not seeing any images) other possibilities to look at are:

- Make sure you're waiting for jQuery to be ready before calling methods. I tend to use `$(document).ready(function { });` as syntax. This could be a problem if the page is rendered before the javascript files have finished loading.
- Check if the images are correctly pathed, i.e do they show correctly without the javascript.

Consider creating a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) for us, put the images and minimal html, css and js in there. It'll help us help you and will probably help you by walking through the process again.